# Running pyjnius on Windows, Linux etc

Tags: android, python, mobile, kivy, pyjnius

While writing a kivy app that uses java api calls through pyjnius, can you run the code on your system's OS like windows, Linux etc. to see how far you've gone and test your progress OR you can only test the code on an android device

Comment: Have you tried it for yourself?

Comment: @Klaus D I haven't yet. I want to know what to expect and all I should install before I start

Comment: Look into Android Virtual device. I think you can test your code on a virtual device using `buildozer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pyjnius works on the desktop, but the Android APIs are not available there so you can't test your Android API calls that way. For this reason, there's not much reason to install pyjnius on the desktop if you're targeting Android.

Comment: Thanks, but how then would one test their applications, would you have to compile into an apk and deploy into an Android mobile everytime or use an emulator?

Comment: Yes, when you want to test the Android API calls.